# PHP: rest of the code ignored when reaching a method call

Tags: php, class

I haven't used PHP in a loooong while, and am having trouble for on thing.

Basically, I have a class file named "database.php" with class "Database" in it.

In my index page, whenever I am reaching the following line, it ignores the reste of the code (works fine in local btw). :

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
$db = Database::getInstance(); //<---- this line

some blablabla
?>
```

Is there a problem with the `__autoload` function ?

Thank you for your help !

NOTE : I uploaded the files on a server that uses Plesk, and I enabled PHP...

Comment: Errors? Check maybe error log or set it to display errors

Comment: i added the "error_reporting(-1);", but it doesnt display the error.

Comment: In fact, there is no error i guess, because it executes the script until it reached this line, if i comment it, then the whole page is here :s I guess there is a probleme with the fact I used objects with PHP, or maybe the way I call the method "getInstance" (Database is a singleton)

Comment: @FloranGmehlin if it gets stuck at that line, it means that there's a fatal error that prevents the rest of the script's execution. Enable error logging and check for errors

Comment: In fact the error was what @F.C. mentionned! I call for "Database" and want to include "database".php. Thank you your time tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of the Capitals :

class Database vs database.php , this might work on windows but not on linux.
Try with [lcfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) in the _autoload function

```
include lcfirst($class_name) . '.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, glad it works. By the way, I don't see your code, but usually , unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, you should use 'require_once' instead of 'include'. That can avoid unexpected side effects. Bonus :  with 'require_once', you would have spotted your mistake rigth away